# При маленьком масштабе в Chrome и IE некоторые блоки сайта разваливаются

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Делаю верстку несложного сайта и заметил одну неприятную вещь - некоторые блоки разваливаются при самом маленьком масштабе в Chrome и IE, не могу понять в чем проблема. Подумал, что это незначительно, так как вряд ли кто будет просматривать сайт в таком масштабе. Зашел, для примера, на фейсбук и вконтакте, и у них тоже при маленьком масштабе некоторые блоки едут куда-то, разваливаются. Я думаю, что и на ряде других крупных сайтах будет подобное. Собственно и возник вопрос, а критично ли такое поведение или лучше исправлять?

Comment: Я ХэшКод только так и просматриваю:  
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/KViuhLV.png)

Comment: Не, ну смех смехом, но ведь и есть сайты, где все отлично. Подгоняли верстку наверное?

Comment: Бывает, что и стандартные шрифты ломают верстку, т.к. при масштабировании сайта шрифты в разных браузерах масштабируются кто как хочет. Соответственно, ширина блока со шрифтом меняет свой размер и верстка вылетает.

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте для:

```
html {
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

Это остановит деформацию

Comment: Деформацию чего?

Comment: @andreyqin т.е падать, разваливаться, не будут

Comment: @navi1893, я знаю, что такое деформация. Я имею в виду - это правило на все элементы страницы действовать будет?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно делать позицию и размеры в относительных единицах.

Например em.

Кстати, проблема реально болючая, и многие известные  сайты тоже грешат этим. Неточности!!!